# Twitterアプリを登録する際のwebsiteの指定(localhost)の可否

Tags: api, twitter

twitterのapiを使ってアプリを作ろうとしており、その際に通常と同様、アプリの情報を求められています。

その際、websiteのURL欄をテストのため、ローカルホスト(127.0.0.1)に指定しようとしています。
[image: 参考画面1]
[image: 参考画面2]

しかし、入力してもInvalid website urlと表示されます。
ただ、2018年5月時点のあるqiitaの記事
[【TwitterAPI】使ってみた(ユーザ情報取得)](https://qiita.com/da-sugi/items/d3c5005c34100121a951)

を見ると、ローカルホストが入力できているように思えます。

パーミッションが足りていないのか、そもそもの仕様が変更されたのか。。
いまいち何が起こっているのか理解できなので、ご存知の方にご教授いただけると幸いです。

Comment: 実際に入力された値は`http://127.0.0.1`でしょうか？既存のアプリのURL変更はできましたので、2018年7月から新規アプリの登録前に[apply for a Twitter developer account](https://developer.twitter.com/en/apply/user)が必要になったタイミングで仕様が変わったのかもしれませんね。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
実際に入力をトライしたのは、"http://127.0.0.1"です。
現状では"http://127.0.0.1"を入力するのを諦め、一旦、自身のtwitterアカウントのURLを登録したら通ったので、それで一時対処している状態です。

やはり仕様変更ですかね。。。ちょっと不便になりましたね笑。
実際にそのような仕様なのか、また公式文書を探ってみます。ありがとうございました！

Comment: 上記、うまくコメントできていませんが、ハイパーリンク部分は`http://127.0.0.1`を指しています。